# strsplit on periods not in quotes

Tags: r, regex

When converting text to columns with `data.table::tstrsplit` I'd like to split on all periods `.` not encased in doublequotes `"`. This task boils down to this situation:

```
test_string <- c('foo.bar.baz', 'fizz.buzz."ba.zz"')
strsplit(test_string, "...", perl = TRUE)
```

To result in:

```
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar" "baz"

[[2]]
[1] "fizz" "buzz" "ba.zz"
```

EDIT: based on the linked duplicate I was able to get this:

```
R> strsplit(test_string, '\\.(?=(?:[^\\"]*\\"[^\\"]*\\")*[^\\"]*$)', perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar" "baz"

[[2]]
[1] "fizz" "buzz" "\"ba.zz\""
```